# Access justification issue using a specification file

Tags: ms-access, specifications

I am using MS Access 2007 and trying to export to a text file using a specification file.

I am having trouble with numerous fields being left justified as numeric fields (exporter treating them as text and left justify).

As an example i will use one field called "Servicer Loan Number". Within my database I have field "Servicer Loan Number" defined as number - long integer.

I created a query and built the following expression for field "Servicer Loan Number"

```
 expServicerLoanNumber: Space(12-Len(Format([Servicer Loan Number],"General Number"))) & Format([Servicer Loan Number],"General Number")
```

Within my spec file I have `expServicerLoanNumber` defined as a Long Integer.

Using the wizard I can step through the export to text process and see that in fact my Space function is working and right justifying `expServicerLoanNumber`. So I select next and visibly see it working on my screen.  HOWEVER once I open the text file in notepad the `expServicerLoanNumber` data column is no longer right justified but rather left justified.

Thinking it may be an export wizard issue I decided to build vba code to call the transfer text function listed below.

```
  DoCmd.TransferText acExportFixed, "QRY_SURF_Extract_Export_Spec", "QRY_SURF_Extract", path & "2001f029_emc_" & (Format(Date, "YYYYMM")) & ".txt", 0
```

This also ignores the Space function and continues to left justify my expServiceroanNumber data column.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  Oh as a side note I converted my MS Access database back to version 2002-03 and still had the same results.

Comment: Have you tried just exporting the fields as-is without your 'Space...'? Once you introduce a space on the front of a number, I believe it will treat it as text?

Comment: Yeah unfortunately that is how I started out trying to export the table to a text file. I did not build any expressions. Once I started researching my justification problem one method to resolve it was adding the expression. Again when stepping through the wizard it truly appears as it is justifying the the data to the right.  Once I click on the finish button and open the file, sure enough the data is left justified.  It almost seems like their is a bug in MS Access 2007 using a spec file.

Comment: What are you using as a delimiter? Are you using fixed-width fields? In 2010, I did comma-delimited, and fixed-width... and both are OK. What happens if you don't use your specification file?

Answer (score -1):

You can use schema.ini file instead transfertext. You can define your fields data type. Check the following blog, it describes all you need to use schema.in file.
https://officeaccelerators.wordpress.com/2015/02/08/exporting-text-file-from-access/